# Laptop hooked to TV shows wrong resolution when only displaying on TV, but correct when duplicating displays

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution, tv

I know there are a lot of posts about TV resolution, but none seemed to match my scenario. I'm running Windows 10 enterprise. I have a laptop, native resolution set to 1080. TV's resolution is also 1080. No scaling or zoom set in Windows 10 or browsers. When I plug in via HDMI and choose the display option to show only display 2 (the TV), the resolution is actually much lower and everything is larger. I have a NVIDIA RTX 2060, TV is a 65" Sony XBR-65X850E.

For example, on my laptop display, the displays options box takes up around 25% of the screen. When displaying on my TV, the box now takes up over 50% of the screen. Can't see or change the resolution in Windows when set to display only on display 2.

The same applies when I extend display as well. When I drag the window from laptop to TV, it goes from correct to wrong. However, if I choose to duplicate displays, then the resolution is correct. Why is this happening? I don't want to duplicate my displays since that will cause performance degradation when using high requirements apps/games.

Comment: How is the TV connected to the computer (DVI, HDMI, VGA, ...?) What version and build of what OS are you using? Does the computer correctly detect the resolution of the TV in the settings?

Comment: HDMI. Windows 10 Enterprise 19042.1526. It appears yes, when I view the settings for the TV. It says Desktop Resolution 1080, Active Signal Resolution also 1080.

Comment: What models are your display adapter and TV?

Comment: NVIDIA RTX 2060, TV is a 65" Sony XBR-65X850E

Comment: So basically what you’re saying is that Windows automatically selects 200% or 250% scaling, correct? That’s about what I’d expect.

Comment: Why would you expect it and why would it do it? And why would it not do that then when I am duplicating displays only? The desktop and signal resolution are the same either way. All I want is the proper resolution, same as on my laptop, but just on a bigger screen without the overhead of duplicating since that wouldn't be too taxing when using something like premiere.

Comment: You already have the proper resolution, obviously. Check again the display scaling setting. Why do I expect this? Because I have a 50″ 4K TV and Windows thinks 250% is a good choice.

Comment: Alright, I feel stupid, apparently there are two scaling settings. I was looking at "Display Settings" by right clicking desktop, an then "Scale and Layout" section. But then I just tried typing into scaling into the search, and it took me to another scaling setting, apparently under System Settings -> Ease of Access -> Vision -> Scaling. That was set to 150%. I set it to 100% and now everything is good. Seems silly there are two different scaling settings in two different places that do the same things.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are two scaling settings. I was looking at "Display Settings" by right clicking desktop, and then "Scale and Layout" section. But then I just tried typing into scaling into the search, and it took me to another scaling setting, apparently under System Settings -> Ease of Access -> Vision -> Scaling. That was set to 150%. I set it to 100% and now everything is good. Seems silly there are two different scaling settings in two different places that do the same things